# How do I create auto increment value for a field in elastic search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm setting up an API for reading employee details, How can I se index ID and employee id  as auto-increment

I'm using express4.17 and elasticsearch7.3

```
const client  = require('../client/esConnect')
module.exports.createAttendance = async (body) => {
    try{
        let payload  = payloadValue(body);
        let response = await client.index(payload);
        return response;
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    }

}
payloadValue = (body) => {
    return payload = {
        index: "attendance",
        type: "_doc",
        id: 4,
        body: {
            empid: body.empid,
            date: body.date,
            present: body.present
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can remember, Elasticsearch does not support (anymore) this kind of auto-increment ID. The ID field is automatically generated as a hash.

However, if you need to store somehow that number, you can add them within your code as another field or just overwriting the ID field.

Remember that Elasticsearch is NOT intended to be used as a Structured / ER database (like SQL).